# Запрос SQL JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Всем привет, проблема в следующем есть запрос в котором я создаю таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                    "name VARCHAR(45),lastname VARCHAR(45),age TINYINT)
```

Все отлично создается, но запрос может дублироваться и нужно проверить перед созданием существует ли данная таблица.
Как я понимаю все должно работать через exists. Но как не могу понять, спасибо за внимание:)

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое @gil9red (Я не знаю как правильно отметить именно, что ты прислал верное решение)
Решение оказалось гениально простое, но видимо пока не для моего развития :D

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
```